# $http dependency injection throwing error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've been working on the CodeSchool AngularJS app, which I've understand so far, but when I began using dependency injections, specifically, $http in order to make an call for my JSON data the app stops working, and I don't know why.  Originally with the first line uncommented the app worked as it should using the variable gems declared within the closure, which is exactly the same code now found in products.json.  I commented out the first line of the controller, and added the appropriate changes to for dependency injection, but now the app doesn't load at all, and it throws the error found below (also see $http-injection.png).

```
    app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', function($http) {
    //this.products = gems; <-- works like this with data in closure
    var store = this;
    store.products = [ ]; // no erros on page load

    $http.get('/data/products.json').success(function( data ) {
        store.products = data;
    });
}]);

Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.10/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=product%20in%20storeCtrl.products&p1=string%3A%0D
at Error (native)
at http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:6:457
at http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:204:24
at Object.<anonymous> (http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:108:144)
at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50)
at g.$digest (http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:109:211)
at g.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
at g.$apply (http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:112:325)
at g.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at g (http://angularjs.dev/angular-1.3/angular.min.js:73:287) angular.js:10811
(anonymous function) angular.js:10811
(anonymous function) angular.js:7962
g.$digest angular.js:12560
$delegate.__proto__.$digest VM8634:844
g.$apply angular.js:12858
$delegate.__proto__.$apply VM8634:855
g angular.js:7380
x angular.js:8527
y.onreadystatechange
```

product.json

```
[
{
    name: 'Hexagonal',
    price: 250.00,
    description: 'The six faces of the hexaonal gem have a habit to excite the eye, and attract good luck.',
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false,
    images: [ ],
    reviews: [
        {
            stars: 5,
            body: "I love this product!",
            author: "mtpultz@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            stars: 1,
            body: "This product sucks!",
            author: "mtpultz@hater.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 1015.25,
    description: 'Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Dodeca is one of those gems.',
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false,
    images: [
        "img/gem-06.gif",
        "img/gem-02.gif",
        "img/gem-01.gif"
    ],
    reviews: [
        {
            stars: 3,
            body: "I think this gem was just OK, could honestly use more shine, IMO.",
            author: "mtpultz@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
            stars: 4,
            body: "Any gem with 12 faces is for me!",
            author: "mtpultz@casensitive.ca"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Pentagonal Gem',
    price: 5.95,
    description: 'Origin of the Pentagonal Gem is unknown, hence its low value.  It has a very high shine and 12 sides however.',
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false,
    images: [
        "img/gem-02.gif",
        "img/gem-06.gif",
        "img/gem-01.gif"
    ],
    reviews: [
        {
            stars: 4,
            body: "The mystery of the Pentagonal Gem makes it sooo fascinating!",
            author: "mtpultz@peanutbutter.com"
        },
        {
            stars: 5,
            body: "I can't get enough of the five faces of the Pentagonal Gem!",
            author: "mtpultz@ketchup.ca"
        }
    ]
}
```

];

[image: output of $http only dependency injection in chrome with batarang plugin]

Originally I was going to try and figure out how to use $log as well, and when I had $log injected it appears as if the json is received (see $http-and-$log-injection.png attached) based on the chrome batarang plugin's output, but the app still doesn't work either way, only the JSON appears on right side of batarang output.

```
    app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
    //this.products = gems;
    var store = this;
    store.products = [ ]; // no erros on page load

    $http.get('/data/products.json').success(function( data ) {
        store.products = data;
    });
}]);
```

[image: output of $http and $log dependency injection in chrome with batarang plugin]

Comment: Can you show `products.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the minified version of Angular while developing. You'll get better error messages when using the non-minified version. But even when you're using the minified version you can get a pretty good idea of what the problem is by visiting the url mentioned first in the exception: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.10/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=product%20in%20storeCtrl.products&p1=string%3A%0D

It seems like you have duplicates in products.json. Without seeing the whole contents of products.json or any of your markup that would be my best guess.

--

**Update**: It seems like `data` is a string and not an array. This is probably because the response body from the server is not properly formatted JSON. Instead of traversing objects in an array, ng-repeat traverses characters in a string and throws an error on the second *tab* character (encoded as %0D) it detects. I've created a plnkr with properly and a bad response as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XbPuXkykzv36NyH3sSeu?p=preview

Comment: Hi, I checked my JSON.  It is only a very small bit of data with three products in an array.  It worked before I used $http, when I was pulling it out of gems in my closure.  I've included the JSON above.

Comment: I'm guessing the server response body isn't properly formatted JSON so `data` is simply parsed as a string, and not as an array. I've created a plnkr as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XbPuXkykzv36NyH3sSeu?p=preview

Comment: hi joakimbi, thanks for pointing out the formatting issue.  I tried JSON.parse(data)  and  angular.fromJson( data ).  The error changed to SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;  I can't figure out why, but it puts it at the dot operator of JSON.parse and similarly for angular.fromJson.  I [posted the project](http://www.casensitive.ca/angularjs/) in case this helps debugging.

Comment: The problem is products.json - it's not properly formatted. Take a look at my plnkr to see what it should look like

Comment: hi, thanks that worked great :)  Thanks for the plnkr, I've never used that before.  Didn't notice the list of files on the left side.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should use $scope:

```
$scope.store = {};
$scope.store.products = [ ]; // no erros on page load

$http.get('/data/products.json').success(function( data ) {
    $scope.store.products = data;
});
```

Comment: The OP may have been using the `as` notation in declaring controllers or `controllerAs` property if it were in a `$roteProvider`, that may explain the line `var store = this;` in his code.

Comment: Hi ryeballar, I wish it was something that complex, but I've only just worked through a starter to Angular lesson by CodeSchool.  They didn't touch on $scope and used this instead, which I recognize from Dojo and jQuery to keep scope.  I'll look into $scope so I can learn how to use it properly.  Incidentally, I did drop this into my code.

Answer (score 0):

`ngRepeat:dupes` error occurs if there are duplicate keys(values in your array/json) in an `ng-repeat` expression, this is because `AngularJS` uses keys to associate `DOM` node with `ng-repeated` items. The requested data products.json may have fields that contain the same value, to solve this, you can append a `track by $index` expression in your `ng-repeat` so that the association of `DOM` node items will be keyed by the index of the your array/json instead of the value of each item.

E.G.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in Store.products track by $index"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it can be for this reason based on the JSON I have, which only includes three items.  I've included my JSON data above in case I have something I don't see or understand wrong.

Comment: can you verify if the data you received is an array or a string?, use Angular.isArray() and log it

Comment: Hi ryeballar, apparently it isn't an array console.log(angular.isArray(data) = false

Comment: did you check if it is a string as well? Angular.isString()

Comment: Hi ryeballar, it's a string, I tried to use eval("(" + data + ')'), but that didn't work.

Comment: use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: hi ryeballar, I tried JSON.parse(data) as well as    eval("(" + data + ")") and  angular.fromJson( data ).  The error changed to SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;  I can't figure out why, but it puts it at the dot operator of JSON.parse and similarly for angular.fromJson.  I [posted the project](http://www.casensitive.ca/angularjs/) in case this helps debugging.